# Issue with text selection in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, selection

I struggle to implement highlight feature in my iOS application, because text selection works poorly in `UIWebView`. It jumps, it flickers, it selects wrong part of article etc. All that misbehavior is attributed to "paragraph snapping".

I have control over the HTML page displayed in my app. Thus I've converted all block elements to inline:

```
p,h1,h2 {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

It helps a bit, but still my selection jumps to the very beginning of paragraph when it shouldn't.

I've tried text selection in iBooks and it works very smoothly there. As far as I know, the iBooks app was built with `UIWebView` as well.

Is there a way to disable 'paragraph snapping' in `UIWebView` or fix text selection somehow??

Comment: Same issue, any progress?